# How to create token for one SharePoint online site collection to access SharePoint search rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to create token for one SharePoint online site collection to access SharePoint search rest api

Example:

if we have site below

https://xxx.sharepoint.com;
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/web1;
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/web2

if I create token, my token should work only for "sites/web1" other site should not work by that token.